# how to filter multiple source file with maven?

Tags: maven, filter, resource-files

i'm trying to filter many source file with maven.
my code work perfectly when i specify the files name.

```
<files>
  <file>
    <source>src/main/default/toto.txt</source>
    <outputDirectory>/default</outputDirectory>
    <filtered>true</filtered>
  </file>
</files>
```

if i have 30 or more files within default directory how can i add the filter?

i tried something like that :

```
<source>src/main/default/*.txt</source>
```

but maven return error

anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the wildcard as mentioned [in the Maven doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html), and in the example below (taken from the afored mentioned website):

```
<resources>
   ....
  <resource>
    <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.txt</include>
      <include>**/*.rtf</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
  ...
</resources>
```